# Print some fields of /etc/passwd

Tags: text-processing, regular-expression, columns, csv

I have a question concerning the usage of wild cards in Linux. Here I have some lines from a long list of lines in the /etc/passwd -file.

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
...
```

What is and appropriate command/commands to print out only the username, UID number and GID number from this line (if possible show multiple ways so I can explore further)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way that doesn't require "wildcards" or regexes is to use `cut`. `cut` can deal with designated-character-separated lines in text files, which `/etc/passwd` just happens to be.

```
cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd
```

The output will have colon-delimited fields.  Looks like GNU `cut` has an extra option, "--output-delimiter", but you could also use `tr`:

```
cut -d: -f1,3,4 /etc/passwd | tr ':' '\t'
```

The options to `cut` work like this:

- `-d:` - use a colon character as a field separator. The default is tab.
- `-f1,3,4` - output fields number 1, 3 and 4. `cut` uses 1-indexed fields, starting at left side of line. Field 2 would be the 'x', where the encrypted password appeared in the past.

The `awk` command could also work:

```
awk -F : '{print $1, $3, $3}' /etc/passwd
```

The `-F :` option tells `awk` to use colons to separate fields. `awk` refers to fields in a line as $1, $2, $3 ... from left to right. $0 holds the entire line, which is often what you want to print out, but not this time.

`sed` can be made to do this:

```
sed 's/^\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):..*/\1 \3 \4/' /etc/passwd
```

In the `sed` command, we finally get to "wildcards", although they seem ugly in this case.

My advice would be to prefer the `cut` command. The `sed` example shows that a regular expression to get what you want can be ugly, and therefore tricky to get correct. `awk` can do more than `cut`, in that `awk` uses runs of whitespace to separate tokens by default.  That can save time over fiddling with a `cut` field separator specification.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `read` builtin:

```
while IFS=: read -r user _ uid gid _; do printf "%s\t%s\t%s\n" "$user" "$uid" "$gid"; done </etc/passwd
```

This sets the field seperator to `:` and discards unwanted variables with `_`, before printing the fields that you do require.